# MysqL big table query optimization

Tags: mysql, large-data

I have a chatting application. I have an api which returns list of users who the user talked. But it takes a long to mysql return a list messages when it reachs 100000 rows of data. 
This is my messages table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
  `_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fromid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `toid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `attachments` text NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `delete` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `uuid_read` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`),
  KEY `fromid` (`fromid`,`toid`,`status`,`delete`,`uuid_read`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=118561 ;
```

and this is my users table (simplified)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `login` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
  `sex` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `status` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `avatar` varchar(30) DEFAULT '0',
  `last_active` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=15523 ;
```

And here is my query (for user with id 1930)

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `u_id`, `id`, `login`, `sex`, `birthdate`, `avatar`, `online_status`, SUM(`count`) as `count`, SUM(`nr_count`) as `nr_count`, `date`, `last_mesg` from
(
(select `m`.`fromid` as `u_id`, `u`.`id`, `u`.`login`, `u`.`sex`, `u`.`birthdate`, `u`.`avatar`, `u`.`last_active` as online_status, COUNT(`m`.`_id`) as `count`, (COUNT(`m`.`_id`)-SUM(`m`.`status`)) as `nr_count`, `tm`.`date` as `date`, `tm`.`message` as `last_mesg` from `messages` as m inner join `messages` as tm on `tm`.`_id`=(select MAX(`_id`) from `messages` as `tmz` where `tmz`.`fromid`=`m`.`fromid`) left join `users` as u on `u`.`id`=`m`.`fromid` where `m`.`toid`=1930 and `m`.`delete` not like '%1930;%' group by `u`.`id`)
UNION
(select `m`.toid as `u_id`, `u`.`id`, `u`.`login`, `u`.`sex`, `u`.`birthdate`, `u`.`avatar`, `u`.`last_active` as online_status, COUNT(`m`.`_id`) as `count`, 0 as `nr_count`, `tm`.`date` as `date`, `tm`.`message` as `last_mesg` from `messages` as m inner join `messages` as tm on `tm`.`_id`=(select MAX(`_id`) from `messages` as `tmz` where `tmz`.`toid`=`m`.`toid`) left join `users` as u on `u`.`id`=`m`.`toid` where `m`.`fromid`=1930 and `m`.`delete` not like '%1930;%' group by `u`.`id`)
order by `date` desc ) as `f` group by `u_id` order by `date` desc limit 0,10
```

Please help to optimize this query

What I need,
Who user talked to (name, sex, and etc)
What was the last message (from me or to me)
Count of messages (all)
Count of unread messages (only to me)

The query works well, but takes too long.

The output must be like this

[image]

Comment: You didn't provide output of `EXPLAIN`. Every MySQL related question has that. From what I can see - you're doing a `LIKE` query with wildcards at beginning and end - that indicates a full table scan (so it goes through entire data of the table). There's no mention of configuration, so we have no clue if MySQL can even utilize your hardware properly. Judging by the issue, you're running default config, on a mechanical drive, no optimzations whatsoever and if you have to perform a `LIKE` search to obtain data for user with id = `1930` then you're querying it completely wrong I'm afraid.

Comment: I have edited question with output picture.
I am adding "user_id+semicolon" to delete column when users deletes message. So in query there is "`m`.`delete` not like '%1930;%'". So deleted messages not to be retrieved.

Comment: What is the purpose of that delete column that you refer to with the LIKE operator? If that is the ID of the user that deleted the message it should be an INT like the ID, if it holds a list of IDs (I'm guessing based on the fact that it is a VARCHAR), then you should rather create a separate join table to hold those IDs.

Comment: The query also takes a long if you remove that condition. But i will test with separate table for deleted messages. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some design problems on your query and database.

- You should avoid keywords as column names, as that `delete` column or the `count` column;
- You should avoid selecting columns not declared in the `group by` without an aggregation function... although MySQL allows this, it's not a standard and you don't have any control on what data will be selected;
- Your `not like` construction may cause a bad behavior on your query because `'%1930;%'` may match `11930;` and 11930 is not equal to 1930;
- You should avoid `like` constructions starting and ending with `%` wildcard, which will cause the text processing to take longer;
- You should design a better way to represent a message deletion, probably a better flag and/or another table to save any important data related with the action;
- Try to `limit` your result before the join conditions (with a derived table) to perform less processing;

I tried to rewrite your query the best way I understood it. I've executed my query in a messages table with ~200.000 rows and no indexes and it performed in 0,15 seconds. But, for sure you should create the right indexes to help it perform better when the amount of data increase.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
  u.id, 
  u.login, 
  u.sex, 
  u.birthdate, 
  u.avatar, 
  u.last_active AS online_status, 
  g._count, 
  CASE WHEN m.toid = 1930 
    THEN g.nr_count 
    ELSE 0 
  END AS nr_count, 
  m.`date`, 
  m.message AS last_mesg 
FROM
(

  SELECT 
    MAX(_id) AS _id, 
    COUNT(*) AS _count, 
    COUNT(*) - SUM(m.status) AS nr_count
  FROM messages m
  WHERE 1=1
    AND m.`delete` NOT LIKE '%1930;%' 
    AND
    (0=1
      OR m.fromid = 1930 
      OR m.toid   = 1930
    )
  GROUP BY 
    CASE WHEN m.fromid = 1930 
      THEN m.toid 
      ELSE m.fromid 
    END
  ORDER BY MAX(`date`) DESC
  LIMIT 0, 10
) g
INNER JOIN messages AS m ON 1=1 
  AND m._id = g._id
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON 0=1 
  OR (m.fromid <> 1930 AND u.id = m.fromid)
  OR (m.toid   <> 1930 AND u.id = m.toid)
ORDER BY m.`date` DESC
;
```

Comment: `LIMIT` does nothing for speeding up queries. It makes them even slower. Although your answer is helpful, I believe that the bullet point about `LIMIT` should be removed.

Comment: @N.B. If you do limit the amount of data that will be joined will not produce any improvement?

Comment: Because of how `LIMIT` works - no, not really. And if the query has to be hugely complex, that almost always means there's a better way.

Comment: @N.B. I think you should describe how `LIMIT` works to explain what exactly is the problem... What I read in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limit-optimization.html) was the opposite: `If you combine LIMIT row_count with ORDER BY, MySQL ends the sorting as soon as it has found the first row_count rows of the sorted result, rather than sorting the entire result. If ordering is done by using an index, this is very fast.`

Comment: No problem - there are two things that have to be taken into consideration when querying. First is that `LIKE %%` scans the whole table, always. The second one is this - `LIMIT X, Y` does this: it takes the whole record set it finds based on condition and then it takes `X` records and discards `Y` records. Without `LIMIT`, you don't deal with discarding - the more you do, the slower it is. The OP's query can't really be optimized because he didn't construct his tables properly, so he ended up dealing with a `LIKE` - that's the core of the problem.

Comment: @N.B. Would you mind include any references about your `LIMIT` statement? It makes sense to me that, if the size of your record set is, lets say, 1000 rows, and you `LIMIT 10` from `OFFSET X`, the lower the X value, the better it will work, e.g., if you'll take 10 rows from offset 10, assuming the `ORDER BY` optimization of `LIMIT`, you'll scan for 20 rows, leaving 980 rows out of processing. And also, it makes sense to me that joining 10 rows is much better than joining 1000 rows.

Comment: Yes, joining 10 rows is better than 1000 rows, but the way you obtain the 10 is what matters. The query we're discussing here is completely wrong, due to how OP constructed his data model. As for the reference on how limit works, I believe it's googleable. If you think about it, a database doesn't know how to return 10 results out of 1000 if it doesn't retrieve the data first, orders it and then gives you what you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100292/discussion-between-felypp-oliveira-and-n-b).

Comment: One addition. After your answer I have checked both results and found that results are different. And then I have found that i have missed one condition in my query, so the "last message" was searched through all messages sent to or from the collocutor user. So after adding " and `tmz`.`toid`=1930" and " and `tmz`.`fromid`=1930" accordingly it worked fine. (0.43 seconds mine against your 0.09 seconds.)
But still your query more rebust than mine. So, thank you very much.